# Can I store JavaScript code in Rails database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a SAT math test question bank
App using rails. Most problems will require unique JavaScript to Create the charts, graphs, and shapes. I want to store this code in the database to be retrieved When I want the app to produce random practice tests for my students to take online and be graded.  Can I store the problem specific JavaScript in the database?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: why don't you represent the charts graphs and shapes in a data structure or even a JSON and load them?

Comment: of course, you could add it on scripts tags in every page you need it dinamically, a couple of problems that come to mind are keeping your strings with html safe and turbolinks not triggering the code, but neither should be much trouble